# WinJS flipview null or undefined error

Tags: javascript, winjs, win-universal-app

I'm trying to attach event to flipView control in WinJS application.

I have HTML in "page2.html"

```
  <div id="galleryTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div class="overlaidItemTemplate">
                    <img class="image " src="#" data-win-bind="src: picture; alt: title" />
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h2 class="ItemTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h2>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
<div id="page2FlipView"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.FlipView"
     data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: EtnologijaGallery.itemList.dataSource, 
                         itemTemplate: galleryTemplate }">
</div>
```

and javascript in pages.define section of "page2.js"

```
   processed: function (element, options) {
        myFilpView = document.getElementById("page2FlipView").winControl.addEventListener("pageselected", handlePageSelected);

        console.log(myFlipView)
    }
```

This code will attach and fire event, but value of myFlipView is "undefined" and i get an error "`Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference`"

I have also tried to add javascript code in ready function in pages.define section, but i get same results.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: The document.getElementById("page2FlipView") returns the element or not ? (it's better to do this to get the element: element.querySelector('page2FlipView')

Comment: console.log(myFlipView) returns "undefined"

Comment: can you post your html and JS file ?

Comment: Project is out of box blank universal windows 8.1 JS app with visual studio 2015. I have added new page template and code from this question. 
There is nothing else, except JS array for data source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finaly found solution. 
I replaced

```
myFilpView = document.getElementById("page2FlipView").winControl;
```

with

```
 myFlipView = element.querySelector('#page2FlipView').winControl;
```

and everything started to work.